# ajax control tool kit file upload

Tags: ajax, file-upload

I am using ajax file upload to upload videos. However, it doesn't allow files bigger then 5 mb. Is it possible to change the limit or do you know any oyher uploader to use for video upload. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the maxRequestLength attribute in the web.config

Comment: this is true for asp.net, on apache its in httpd.conf via LimitRequestBody <filesize> (bytes). The max is 2GB and you will also need to take care of max-script runtime (timeout).

Comment: <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />  workerd. it allows up to 1gb files.